# How to make a smaller gap when using many level of $$$$?

Tags: mathjax

I have the following problem:

[image]

Where I'm using $$$$ twice to make the equation of the linear model fit horizontally.

But I don't like white space that's left between the two lines.

Is there a way to perhaps make the two lines with less white space between them?

Comment: The vertical space around these equations is `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`.

Comment: don't use repeated `$$` use a multiline display such as `align` or `split`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you provide more info?

Comment: there are loads of examples of split on site, see egregs answer here:

Comment: @mavavilj: Are you talking specifically about using `$$` in MathJax?

Comment: @Werner I'm using it in MathJax, but I believe `$$` behaves the same in Latex as well.

Comment: @mavavilj: Consider using an `array` instead. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCTE.png).